# Where is a "global bootstrap place" in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to install [kylekatarnls/business-day package](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day) into Laravel 6. The docs say to "First load the mixin in some global bootstrap place of your app:". Where do I put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to place this in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Cmixin\BusinessDay;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $additional_holidays = [
            // ...
        ];

        BusinessDay::enable(\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::class, 'us-national', $additional_holidays);
    }
}
```

Another option is to create your own [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers) and place the code in the new service provider's `boot` method.